# Model diagnostic plots

Tags: r, data-visualization, predictive-models, diagnostic

i have built a predictive model and these are the model diagnostic. How do i interpret them? it looks like the model is linear based on the residuals vs fitted plot. but what about others?

[image]

Comment: I've voted to have this moved to [stats.se] because it's about statistics rather than programming. However, there's pretty much no information here (what type of model, what the goal of your model is, what constraints you might have, etc), and they'll probably need to know more in order to help

Comment: You need to tell us (as an edit to the post!), at least what kind of model did you fit!